# make a panel form in the center of the page

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

so I was trying to create a form panel with Twitter Bootstrap into the center of the page, and hopefully even when the browser is resizing, it still be at the center, 
[here's](http://jsfiddle.net/M292j/) what I tried on jsfiddle, the problem is I can't seem to make it center, anyone had ideas? the full code is in below

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <legend>User Login</legend>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail">
                                Username</label>
                            <input id="inputEmail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: John.Doe"
                                required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword">
                                Password</label>
                            <input id="inputPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="*******"
                                required="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input id="chkRememberMe" type="checkbox" />
                                Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn navbar-custom">
                            Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the preview:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please replace

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
```

with this

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="max-width:400px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use columns to size and center your panel, for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <legend>User Login</legend>

                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                            <input id="inputEmail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: John.Doe" required="" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                            <input id="inputPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="*******" required="" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input id="chkRememberMe" type="checkbox" />
                                Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn navbar-custom">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margins in the div's style attribute:

```
style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"
```

Hope it works...